# how to fix file upload images in laravel ->move() function

Tags: php, laravel

i am try to upload image using file images
but display this error

```
=> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException
Could not move the file "C:\xampp\tmp\phpB3DB.tmp" to "works_images\2020-06-25 08:35:57before.jpg" (move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB3DB.tmp' to 'works_images\2020-06-25 08:35:57before.jpg').
```

i am use this code in Tratis to upload Image what the error ?

```
public function saveImage($imgBefore , $imgAfter , $folder){
   $file_extention1 = $imgBefore->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $file_extention2 = $imgAfter->getClientOriginalExtension();

   $fileName1 = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString().'before.'.$file_extention1;
   $fileName2 = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString().'after.'.$file_extention2;

   $path = $folder;

   $imgBefore->move($path , $fileName1);
   $imgAfter->move($path , $fileName2);
   return [$fileName1,$fileName2]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurs **using reserved characters in a file name**

This is how you getting the file name:

```
$fileName1 = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString().'before.'.$file_extention1;
$fileName2 = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString().'after.'.$file_extention2;
// Output
// 2020-06-25 08:35:57before.jpg
```

This would mean that the eventual file name would have characters like `-`,  `:` and `blank space`.  On reading this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words , realised that the **: (colon)** is a reserved character and once you got rid of it (by amending the timestamp section like `date('Ymd_His')`)

Try this :

```
$fileName1 = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'before.'.$file_extention1;
$fileName2 = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'after.'.$file_extention2;
```

Comment: when i test in ubuntu it's work
but this error only in window

Comment: @Hussain you can use `time()` instead of `Carbon`, your name will be unique.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Or format your date, if you want to use Carbon,  Like `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s')`